# PHP script to export products to XML per store?

Tags: php, magento

So, I have a daily cron job running a file that calls another file that in combination export our product list to an XML file. These are the two files.

arrayxml.php

```
<?php
class ArrayXml {

    private $xml;

    public function __construct($root='store') {
        $this->xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<$root></$root>");
    }

    private function iterate($element, $xmlNode) {
        foreach($element as $name=>$value) {
            if(is_string($value) || is_numeric($value)) {
                $xmlNode->$name = $value;
            } 
            else {
                $xmlNode->$name = null;
                $this->iterate($value, $xmlNode->$name);
            }
        }
    }
    public function toXML($array) {
        $this->iterate($array, $this->xml);
        return $this->xml->asXML();
    }
}
?>
```

and export.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    include '../app/Mage.php';
    include 'arrayxml.php';

    Mage::app();

    $_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $_result = array();

    foreach($_products as $_product) {
        $_product = $_product->load();

        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
        if (isset($categoryIds[0])){
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($categoryIds[0]);
            $categoryName = $category->getName();
        }

        $_result['products']['product'][] = array(
            'productId' => $_product->getSku(),
            'title' => $_product->getName(),
            'description' => $_product->getDescription(),
            'price' => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
            'image' => 'http://dissios.com/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(),
            'url' => 'http://dissios.com/'.$_product->getUrlPath(),
            'instock' => 'Y',
            'availability' => 'Διαθέσιμο',
            'category_id' => $categoryIds[0],
            'category_name' => $categoryName
        );
    }
    $_converter = new ArrayXML();
    echo $_converter->toXML($_result);
    $f = fopen("bestprice.xml", "w");
    fwrite($f, $_converter->toXML($_result));
    fclose($f);
?>
```

Since then, I've split the site to separate stores/views, so there are two domains that i want the products to have URLs of, not the parent store's (dissios.com in the code above).

I'd like this code to check the store code and adjust the URL accordingly, so I'd have for example http://eclock.gr/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage() for the one and http://lourakiahirsch.gr/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage() for the other.

Thanks!

EDIT: Solved!

Here is the code i changed:

```
// Get the product's store IDs
    $storeCode = $_product->getStoreIds();

    if ($storeCode[2] == '5') {

       $_result['products']['product'][] = array(
                'productId' => $_product->getSku(),
                'title' => $_product->getName(),
                'description' => $_product->getDescription(),
                'price' => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
                'image' => 'http://lourakiahirsch.gr/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(),
                'url' => 'http://lourakiahirsch.gr/'.$_product->getUrlPath(),
                'instock' => 'Y',
                'availability' => 'Διαθέσιμο',
                'category_id' => $categoryIds[0],
                'category_name' => $categoryName
            );
    }
    else if ($storeCode[2] == '6') {

        $_result['products']['product'][] = array(
           'productId' => $_product->getSku(),
           'title' => $_product->getName(),
           'description' => $_product->getDescription(),
           'price' => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
           'image' => 'http://eclock.gr/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(),
           'url' => 'http://eclock.gr/'.$_product->getUrlPath(),
           'instock' => 'Y',
           'availability' => 'Διαθέσιμο',
           'category_id' => $categoryIds[0],
           'category_name' => $categoryName
            );
    }
    else {
        $_result['products']['product'][] = array(
            'productId' => $_product->getSku(),
                'title' => $_product->getName(),
                'description' => $_product->getDescription(),
                'price' => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
                'image' => 'http://dissios.com/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(),
                'url' => 'http://dissios.com/'.$_product->getUrlPath(),
                'instock' => 'Y',
                'availability' => 'Διαθέσιμο',
                'category_id' => $categoryIds[0],
                'category_name' => $categoryName
            );
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, if you have a lot of products, dont use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()`, because you will have a problem with memory limit and so on. Use Iterator to extract from DD, for example 100 products per query

Comment: @sergio thanks, what should i use? we don't have a lot of products though, less than 1000 total over the two sites. any ideas on how to separate the URLs per store?

Comment: About iterator - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16540/best-way-to-iterate-through-product-collection, about URLs need to check

Answer (score 0):

As one possible way to do this, you can store your stores' ID (you can find them in Magento Admin panel) in one array and then loop through them using something like this:

```
foreach($arrayOfStores as $storeId) {
       $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
```

And then you load your collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId( $storeId )
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the structure of the files as similar to what i have now as possible, i'm not 100% i understand your code but it looks like i'd have to change the code to accommodate?
I basically want two cases, depending on the store code, to have separate URLs for 'url' and 'image' inside the $_result['products']['product'][] array.